# How to clean up an interrupted Homebrew install?

Tags: homebrew

I recently decided to brew install stack, the Haskell package manager, but changed my mind midway and interrupted with ctrl+c.  It looks like a reasonable amount of storage has been taken up on my computer by the install, however, so I think the downloaded files from the installation remain.  How can I clean them out?

I've already tried brew cleanup but it only cleared a few things, maybe 20 mb in total.  Is there a way to completely remove the remains of an interrupted Homebrew install?  If not, any tips for going about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tired `brew doctor` ? It usually gives a good idea of what might be going wrong. I would then suggest looking into the Cellar folder and search for leftovers.

Answer (score -1):

Run the command

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"
```

There will be files that will not be deleted, delete them manually. Deleting this worked for me `/usr/local/Homebrew/`

Comment: this uninstalls homebrew itself while OP wants one download of `stack` to be removed.